# Requisição de serviço em PHP

Tags: php, cliente-servidor

Estou fazendo um exercício de Cliente/Servidor, tenho um sql com vários registros de produtos e consigo LISTAR TODOS, FILTRAR POR PREÇO e FILTRAR POR CODIGO, mas na hora de implementar o serviço de alterar estoque, ele não reconhece minha fuction. A parte 1 eu consegui realizar, a partir do 3º tópico da parte 2 não consegui ...colocarei o enunciado e os códigos! Valeu quem ajudar

ENUNCIADO EXERCÍCIO
**Parte 1:** *Instalação*

- Faça o clone dos arquivos desta pasta na sua máquina
- Importe o arquivo base.sql no MySQL, usando a ferramenta de sua preferência
- Coloque o arquivo catalog.php no diretório httdos do Apache da sua
  máquina
- Teste a conexão acessando o arquivo php no seu computador, indicando
  o caminho do arquivo. Exemplo: http://localhost/catalog.php?op=list
- Teste outros serviços implementados

**Parte 2:** *Criação da aplicação cliente*

- Crie uma aplicação cliente, usando os conceitos mostrados nas aulas
  anteriores.
- Sua aplicação cliente deve acessar o serviço implantado na parte 1,
  passando os valores escolhidos pelo usuário
- Implemente o processamento da resposta, mostrando os dados de maneira
  clara ao usuário. Note que o serviço catalog.php devolve os dados em
  formato JSON
- Seu trabalho será converter essa resposta em algo mais legível para
  usuários não-técnicos (exemplo: usando table para mostrar os dados)

**Parte 3:** *Criação de novos serviços*

- No arquivo catalog.php, foram implementados 3 serviços
- Crie novos serviços que podem ser executados por aplicações clientes
- Alguns exemplos: inserir produto, excluir produto, aumentar estoque
  de um produto, reajustar preço de um ou mais produtos

```php
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','aula3_clientserver');
$op = $_GET["op"];
switch ($op) {
    case "list":
        listar($mysqli);
        break;
    case "filterCode":
        getByCode($mysqli, $_GET["code"]);
        break;
    case "filterPrice":
        getByPrice($mysqli, $_GET["from"],$_GET["to"]);
        break;
    case "updateEstoque":
        setEstoque($mysqli, $_GET["code"],$_GET["qtd"]);
        break;
    default: 
        echo "Operacao invalida";
        break;
}
function listar($mysqli) {
    $query = "SELECT produto_id, nome, estoque, preco from produto";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $dbdata = array();
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dbdata[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($dbdata);
}
function getByCode($mysqli, $code) {
    $query = "SELECT produto_id, nome, estoque, preco from produto where nome='".$code."'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $dbdata = array();

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dbdata[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($dbdata);
}
function getByPrice($mysqli, $from, $to) {
    $query = "SELECT produto_id, nome, estoque, preco from produto where preco>=".$from." AND preco<=".$to;
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $dbdata = array();

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dbdata[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($dbdata);
}
//AUMENTAR ESTOQUE
function setEstoque($mysqli, $code, $qtd) {
    $query = "UPDATE produto SET estoque = estoque +".$qtd." WHERE nome ='".$code."'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
}
?>
```

Comment: O enunciado é apenas texto, não tem porque colocar aqui como imagem. Por favor, transcreva o enunciado como texto; isso ajudará na busca do site e permitirá que usuários que não podem visualizar a imagem te ajudar. Aproveitando, **não** utilize o snippet do site para PHP; está bem claro nele que é para código HTML/JavaScript/CSS. Quando for [edit] a pergunta, coloque também as mensagens de erros. Não temos como adivinhar isso.

Comment: Qual é o erro que aparece?

Comment: Ele não está nem reconhecendo minha function SetEstoque... Não manjo muito de PHP

Comment: `$_GET['op']` é exatamente `"setEstoque"`? Por que se for `"SetEstoque"` não vai funcionar, a comparação é *case sensitive*.

Comment: Ela está exatamente como setEstoque